# PHP MySQL CREATE TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, create-table

I'm trying to create a table using PHP, PDO and MySQL.
For the needs of my application, the name of the table has to be a variable.

Here is my code :

```
$request = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS :table (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `parent_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `position` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `left` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `right` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `level` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
      `type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;");
$request->execute(array(
    'table'=>$uuid));
```

Can't I use ":table" in the MySQL statement ??
Currently I wrote :

```
[...]
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$uuid`
[...]
```

This works but it sounds weird to me ^^' Is it the only solution to my problem ?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($uuid);`?

Comment: What happens whey you try to execute the version with :table?

Comment: @rekire $uuid contains the result of uniqid("", true) which I use to generate random IDs

Comment: @DWright the version with :table doesn't work. It does nothing (no error)

Comment: And this is why I won't be moving away from the `mysql` extension anytime soon.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass the table name as parameter. If you want to create table with variable name you must use dynamic query.

Comment: I don't get it... ^^' I just need to create one table each time someone register on my website (one new user = one new table). Are dynamic queries really what I need ? How would you do it ?

Comment: "one new user = one new table" worst design. Include `UserId` field which references to your users table PK.

Comment: Hokobyan I know it's a really bad design. But I'm running out of time for this project and this seems to be the simpliest version.
I have a table which contains all my users and each users can store files online and access them trough a "tree-view". So each user has a table (like the one i'm trying to create using variable name) in which files are stored. The name of the table corresponds to the user id.

Comment: @Eschard1991: I have to agree with Hakobyan... Youre headed to a land full of FAIL....

Comment: "But I'm running out of time for this project and this seems to be the simplest version." Do you know what is the `technical debt`. Read about this and you will understand that not the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pdo->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userfiles (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `left` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `right` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `level` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");
```

This is THE ONLY proper way of handling such situations.
Such matters are very basic things.
and your current setup is just like a car with square wheels.
Despite of your shortage of time you have to make it single table.
Otherwise you will waste A LOT more time and eventually will turn to the proper design anyway but after innumerable pains